# Playgrounds - How to save a file? Getting no permission

Tags: macos, swift-playground

Using Playgrounds 4.3 on macOS 13, I am trying to save a file, in this case an JSON file, to disk.

As an example I use this code, so it should work but not in Playgrounds.
Are there setting that i should set or use to get this work?

```
    import Foundation

struct Driver: Codable { 
    let name: String
    let ownsCar: Bool
    let license_code: String?
    
    init(name: String, ownsCar: Bool, license_code: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.ownsCar = ownsCar
        self.license_code = license_code
    }
}

class Drivers {
    let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/la/JSON/JSONTestFile.json")
    
    var data: Driver = Driver(name: "Picard", ownsCar: true)
    
    func readFromFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
        let readData = try Data(contentsOf: filePathURL)
        self.data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Driver.self, from: readData)
    }
    
    func writeToFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
        let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.data)
        try jsonData.write(to: filePathURL)
    }
    
}
let drivers: Drivers = Drivers()
do {
    try drivers.writeToFile(filePathURL: drivers.filePathURL )
}
catch {
    print("Error saving file at path: \(drivers.filePathURL) with error: \(error)")
}
```

the result error is:

> Error saving file at path: file:///Users/la/JSON/JSONTestFile.json
> with error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have
> permission to save the file “JSONTestFile.json” in the folder “JSON”."
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/la/JSON/JSONTestFile.json,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x7f88474252b0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
> Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

What can and should I do?

BTW I did try this before with also no joy.

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport
import Swift

struct Driver: Codable {
    let name: String
    let ownsCar: Bool
    let license_code: String?
    
    init(name: String, ownsCar: Bool, license_code: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.ownsCar = ownsCar
        self.license_code = license_code
    }
}

class Drivers {
  let filePathURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/la/Documents/Shared Playground Data/JSONTestFile.json")
  //  print (playgroundSharedDataDirectory)
   // let filePathURL = playgroundSharedDataDirectory.appendingPathComponent("JSONTestFile.json")
    
    var data: Driver = Driver(name: "Picard", ownsCar: true)
    
    func readFromFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
        let readData = try Data(contentsOf: filePathURL)
        self.data = try JSONDecoder().decode(Driver.self, from: readData)
    }
    
    func writeToFile(filePathURL: URL) throws {
        let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(self.data)
        try jsonData.write(to: filePathURL)
    }
    
}
let drivers: Drivers = Drivers()
do {
    try drivers.writeToFile(filePathURL: drivers.filePathURL )
}
catch {
    print("Error saving file at path: \(drivers.filePathURL) with error: \(error)")
}
```

> 'playgroundSharedDataDirectory' is unavailable:
> playgroundSharedDataDirectory is not supported in Swift Playgrounds

any suggestions available?

edit
@Brixxon Tulabing's - What is the difference between the both of our code

```
 let fileName = "JSONTestFile.json"

let docDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]

let outputFileUrl = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    func documentDirectoryURL() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }

    func filePathURL() -> URL {
        return documentDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    }
```

Mine gives an error your say its was written, but there is no written file

Comment: Is "la" your username?

Comment: yes, this is here my user name; but it doesn't work either with a different account AND different machine

Comment: The problem is that when you run the Playgrounds app the home directory isn't your own home directory but it exists inside a container at a different path and you will only have write permission inside this container and hence the error. You can't hardcode the path as you have done instead you need to do is to use NSHomeDirectory() to get the correct path and work from there. So start with `URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())` instead and then use functions in [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) to create sub folders and files

Comment: the issue is when I use let outputFileUrl = docDirectory.appendingPathComponent(fileName) the path doesn't exists and is not created; why does Apple provide those samples and it did work before? The constant playgroundSharedDataDirectory is also not working. The hardcoded path was just a an example, btwe I did try NSHomeDirectory also a no go.

Answer (score 0):

The constant *playgroundSharedDataDirectory* isn't working for now (anymore?), someone some information about this?

I did try other options like I mentioned above in the code and also mentioned by Brixxon and Jonkim.

However there was an error or nothing to find. Testing and searching the file, I did get file not found and even the part didn't exist, mainly "*../com.apple.PlaygroundsMac.ExecutionExtension/..*"

After looking to the path, searching the containers folder there is no "*com.apple.PlaygroundsMac.ExecutionExtension*" folder. Using the terminal, I did

```
'open "../com.apple.PlaygroundsMac.ExecutionExtension"'
```

It did open and shows nothing at first. The name of the folder in the containers folders is "***ExecutionExtension***" and not "*com.apple.PlaygroundsMac.ExecutionExtension*". Hidden secret? At least I didnt't know.

Some of the successfully written files are there.

Thank you for open the folder; i ment my eyes. ;)